# Url redirect using htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have a website I am trying to migrate to a new host. After migrating to the new host, all the images are broken due to the path not being correct.

Site was migrated to:

`http://www.indianradio.net.au/indiantimes.com.au/`

The image paths are broken, an example of one:
`http://www.indianradio.net.au/cms/fckeditor/editor/userfiles/image/Oct-14-Gaura.jpg`

In order to work, the path needs to be:

`http://www.indianradio.net.au/indiantimes.com.au/cms/fckeditor/editor/userfiles/image/Oct-14-Gaura.jpg`

What is the best way to change the urls to a base of:

`http://www.indianradio.net.au/indiantimes.com.au/`

so they all function correctly.

I was under the impression I could do this with .htaccess, but I am unable to figure out how to do so. Any help would be much appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: don't you have a place where to change the image path ? htaccess is not a good ideea because all those rules in there will be parsed on every request..

Answer (score 1):

You could use this:

`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/indiantimes.com.au/.*
RewriteRule ^(.*\.(gif|jpg|png))$ indiantimes.com.au/$1 [L]` - untested

But I highly recomend finding a way to change the images path in the script and
not using htaccess.